# Dygraphs in R: Plot Ribbon and mean line of different groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, dygraphs

I recently started working dygraphs in R, and wanted to achieve a ribbon line plot with it.

Currently, I have the below ggplot which displays a ribbon (for data from multiple batches over time) and its median for two groups. Below is the code for it.
[image]

```
ggplot(df, 
       aes(x=variable, y=A, color=`[category]`, fill = `[category]`)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "ribbon", alpha = 0.35) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", size = 0.9) +
  theme_minimal()+ labs(x="TimeStamp")
```

I could add the median solid line on the dygraph, but I'm unable to add the ribbon to it. Below is the dygraph and my code for it.

[image]

```
df_Medians<- df%>%
  group_by(variable,`[category]`) %>%
  summarise(A = median(A[!is.na(A)]))

median <- cbind(as.ts(df_Medians$A))

dygraph(median) %>% 
  dyRangeSelector()
```

Is there anyway to plot something similar to the above ggplot on dygraphs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `stat_summary`'s default function is `mean_se`, which produces the mean rather than the median. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying both in mean and median in two plots. So a solution for mean would work too

Answer (score 0):

See if the following serves your purpose:

**ggplot code** (for mean, replace `median_se` with `mean_se` in the `stat_summary` layers):

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, 
       aes(x=variable, y=A, color=category, fill = category)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "ribbon", alpha = 0.35, fun.data = median_se) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", size = 0.9, fun.data = median_se) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: ggplot version]

**dygraph code** (for mean, replace `median_se` with `mean_se` in the `summarise` step):

```
library(dplyr)
library(dygraph)

# calculate summary statistics for each category, & spread results out such that each row
# corresponds to one position on the x-axis
df_dygraph <- df %>%
  
  group_by(variable, category) %>%
  summarise(data = list(median_se(A))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  tidyr::unnest(data) %>%
  mutate(category = as.integer(factor(category))) %>% # optional: standardizes the column 
                                                      # names for summary stats
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = variable, names_from = category,
                     values_from = c(ymin, y, ymax))

> head(df_dygraph)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  variable ymin_1 ymin_2   y_1   y_2 ymax_1 ymax_2
     <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1        1  3817.  2712. 4560. 2918.  5304.  3125.
2        2  3848.  2712. 4564. 2918.  5279.  3125.
3        3  3847.  2826. 4564  2961   5281.  3096.
4        4  3722.  2827. 4331  2962.  4940.  3098.
5        5  3833.  2831. 4570. 2963   5306.  3095.
6        6  3835.  2831. 4572  2964   5309.  3097.

dygraph(df_dygraph, main = "Dygraph title") %>%
  dySeries(c("ymin_1", "y_1", "ymax_1"), label = "Category 1") %>%
  dySeries(c("ymin_2", "y_2", "ymax_2"), label = "Category 2") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector()
```

[image: dygraph version]

Code for median counterpart of `mean_se`:

```
median_se <- function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x)
  se <- sqrt(var(x) / length(x))
  med <- median(x)
  ggplot2:::new_data_frame(list(y = med, 
                                ymin = med - se, 
                                ymax = med + se),
                           n = 1)
}
```

Sample data:

```
df <- diamonds %>%
  select(price, cut) %>%
  filter(cut %in% c("Fair", "Ideal")) %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  slice(1:1000) %>%
  mutate(variable = rep(seq(1, 50), times = 20)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rename(A = price, category = cut)
```

Comment: In case of the median, I do not want to show the ribbon with ymin=med-se and ymax=med+se. Instead, I want to show the ymin = lowest number at that timestamp and ymax = highest number at that timestamp among all batches. Can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean **don't** want a separate ribbon for each batch (which appears to be the original intent)? Since the global min/max at each time stamp across all the batches would be the same for each batch's ribbon.